# Create new Stripe checkout link with new Firestore Entry

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently doing a fundraiser page and I am still struggling on how to make a new Stripe payment link with the creation of a new entry on Firestore database. How do I implement it, as I am kind of struggling with it? Thanks.

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('KEY_HERE');
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  success_url: 'https://example.com/success',
  line_items: [
    {
      price: 'PriceHere',
      quantity: 1,
    },
  ],
  mode: 'payment',
});

const addFundr = document.querySelector(".add");
addFundr.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  addDoc(collRef, {
    fundName: addFundr.fundName.value,
    fundAmount: addFundr.fundAmount.value,
    fundDesc: addFundr.fundDesc.value,
  }).then(() => {
    alert("Fundraiser created");
    window.location.href = "/fundraise/fundraise.html";
  });
});
```